# Nativescript API LEVEL

Tags: android, nativescript

I built an android app with Nativescript framework, I tried to upload my SDK to play store and am getting this error below

"**Your app currently targets API level 25 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 26.**"

I have change the API LEVEL in AndroidManifest.xml but that doesn't seems to work, how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 5):

After changing the targetSdkVersion in `AndroidManifest.xml` make a clean rebuild to amek sure that the changes are applied in the Android project.

If the above is not working you could explicitly set the `targetSdkVersion` in your project's `app.gradle` file as done [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle#L11)

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the experience with NativeScript6 project, which upgrade the API level to 33 and released on the Google Play.

You should update 3 files:

- [Project Root] >> **App_Resources** >> **Android** >> **app.gradle**
- [Project Root] >> **App_Resources** >> **Android** >> **src** >> **main** >> **AndroidManifest.xml**
- [Project Root] >> **references.d.ts**

1. Update **app.gradle** file add **minSdkVersion** and
   **targetSdkVersion**.

   ```json
   android{
       defaultConfig{
           ...
           minSdkVersion 29
           targetSdkVersion 33
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Update **AndroidManifest.xml**

   ```xml
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       ...
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="33"/>
       ...
       <application ...>
           <activity ... android:exported="true">
               ...
           </activity>
           ...
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```
3. Update the **references.d.ts** file (Option)

   ```js
   /// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
   /// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android-24.d.ts" />
   ```

After completing the above operations, delete folders **node_modules** and **platforms** and rebuild your project.

---

Why the **minSdkVersion** is not set to 33?

Because the **minSdkVersion** determines whether refer to the latest permission required for advertising ID in Google Play services.

[Behavior changes: Apps targeting Android 13 or higher](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#gms)

You can decide whether to do this.

Hope it helps you！